# VBA equivalent in VB.NET

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, path, unc

I have a VBA Module which is working in excel, When I converted it to VB.net I receive error
"The UNC path should be of the form \\server\share."

VBA Excel Module 1:

```
   Global MyFolder As String
   Global MyFile As Variant
   Global eRow As Long
   Global Crow As Long

   Public Sub Browsing()
   With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    Err.Clear
   End With
   MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\", vbReadOnly)
End Sub
```

Converted VB.net Code
Module 1

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Module Module1
    Public MyFolder As String
    Public MyFile As VariantType
    Public eRow As Long
    Public Crow As Long
    Public Sub Browsing()
        Dim xl As New Excel.Application
        With xl.Application.FileDialog(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .Show()
            MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
            Err.Clear()
        End With
        **MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\", FileAttribute.ReadOnly)**
    End Sub
End Module
```

Error : "The UNC path should be of the form \\server\share."

Appreciate your help

Thanks, Regards

Moheb Labib

Comment: What does the path actually look like? If that's what you're being told the problem is, maybe it's worthwhile actually looking at it and, if you expect us to help, showing us.

Comment: There is a "\" on the end of `MyFolder` already, and then another "\" is appended in the `Dir` function. Perhaps the "\\" is confusing it.

Comment: Change `SelectedItems(1)` to `.SelectedItems(0)` because of `AllowMultiSelect = False`

Comment: Use Path.Comine() to construct file paths rather string concatenations.    Much more reliable

Comment: @  Mo Khalefa , Thanks it passed this line